# cap deploy: does not appear to be a git repository problems deploying rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I have some serious issues deploying my rails 3 app.
There isn't a post on StackOverflow with an answer to this issue.

Anyone might have happened this to them and knows how to fix? Thanks in advance.

```
dev:test me$ cap deploy
  * executing `deploy'
  * executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    executing locally: "git ls-remote ssh://root@myserver.net/srv/test master"
root@myserver.net's password: 
    command finished in 4102ms
  * executing "git clone --depth 1 ssh://root@myserver.net/srv/test /srv/test/releases/20111025125230 && cd /srv/test/releases/20111025125230 && git checkout -b deploy eb6e04f696aed7a13ee58633ca68902a010685b0 && git submodule init && git submodule sync && export GIT_RECURSIVE=$([ ! \"`git --version`\" \\< \"git version 1.6.5\" ] && echo --recursive) && git submodule update --init $GIT_RECURSIVE && rm -Rf /srv/test/releases/20111025125230/.git && (echo eb6e04f696aed7a13ee58633ca68902a010685b0 > /srv/test/releases/20111025125230/REVISION)"
    servers: ["myserver.net"]
Password: 
    [myserver.net] executing command
 ** [myserver.net :: out] Initialized empty Git repository in /srv/test/releases/20111025125230/.git/
 ** [myserver.net :: out] root@myserver.net's password:
Password: 
 ** [myserver.net :: out]
 ** [myserver.net :: out] fatal: '/srv/test' does not appear to be a git repository
 ** [myserver.net :: out] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
    command finished in 3930ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /srv/test/releases/20111025125230; true"
    servers: ["myserver.net"]
    [myserver.net] executing command
    command finished in 920ms
failed: "rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell '@global' -c 'git clone --depth 1 ssh://root@myserver.net/srv/test /srv/test/releases/20111025125230 && cd /srv/test/releases/20111025125230 && git checkout -b deploy eb6e04f696aed7a13ee58633ca68902a010685b0 && git submodule init && git submodule sync && export GIT_RECURSIVE=$([ ! \"`git --version`\" \\< \"git version 1.6.5\" ] && echo --recursive) && git submodule update --init $GIT_RECURSIVE && rm -Rf /srv/test/releases/20111025125230/.git && (echo eb6e04f696aed7a13ee58633ca68902a010685b0 > /srv/test/releases/20111025125230/REVISION)'" on myserver.net
dev:test me$
```

Comment: Are you sure your repository is in /srv/test ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means the path `ssh://root@myserver.net/srv/test` is not a git repository.

Make sure the path is correct. Login into `myserver.net` server, cd to `/srv/test` and verify the content of that folder. Then change the `deploy.rb` file accordingly.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by verify?